# Как в .cgi скрипт передать параметр через shell

Tags: cgi, unix

Есть скрипт  (Ubuntu) .cgi ... он выводит страничку Html. В самом html вызов этого скрипта с параметрами написан так (они и работает ок) `day_detail.cgi?year=2013&month=07&day=07`. Хочу в самой ос сделать вывод в текстовик, для личных нужд. Делаю так через shell: `./day_detail.cgi?year=2013&month=07&day=07  > /var/www/posmotr.txt`  -  выдает ошибку.

Как? спасибо.

Comment: какую ошибку?

Comment: Что Вы храните в скрипте? Через shell его можно пустить если это соответствующий скрипт.

Comment: root@ubuntu-stat:/var/www/lightsquid# ./day_detail.cgi?year=2013&month=07&day=07  > /var/www/posmotr.txt
[1] 2778
[2] 2779
bash: ./day_detail.cgi?year=2013: Нет такого файла или каталога
[1]-  Выход из 127     ./day_detail.cgi?year=2013

Comment: скрипт от lightsquid

Comment: И правильно выдаёт. Ищет файл day_detail.cgi?year... (и т.д.). И где же он его найдёт?

Comment: я это понимаю ... за знаком вопрос стоит передаваемый параметр, что то должно стоять вместо знака вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо прежде задать нужные переменные окружения. Как минимум, *REQUEST_METHOD* и *QUERY_STRING*, но скрипту могут понадобиться и другие.
После чего запускаем:

```
#!/bin/bash

export REQUEST_METHOD=GET
export QUERY_STRING="year=2013&month=07&day=07"
/path/to/script/directory/script.cgi
```

Или же, если хочется непосредственно из терминала осуществлять запуск, то попробуйте что-то типа

```
env REQUEST_METHOD=GET env QUERY_STRING="year=2013&month=07&day=07" ./script.cgi
```

Разумеется, script.cgi должен иметь +x.

Answer (score 0):

На Вашем месте я бы запускал этот скрипт на веб-сервере, а через него передавал вывод в файл. Но всё зависит от того, что за скрипт у вас, на чем написан и что именно делает.

Comment: скрипт не мой, это скрипт от lightsquid (анализатор логов).

Comment: Тогда Вам точно это дело заворачивать надо через вебсервер.

Comment: на perl скрипт